# Batch Error input into file

Tags: php, html, batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (inbox.html) do (
   findstr /N ^^ "%%f" > "%%~Nf.tmp"
   echo :EOF>> "%%~Nf.tmp"
   call :InsertLine1 < "%%~Nf.tmp" > "%%~Nf.out"
   REM del "%%f"
   REM del "%%~Nf.tmp"
   REM ren "%%~Nf.out" "%%~Nf.php"
)
goto :EOF

:InsertLine1
for /L %%i in (1,1,0) do (
   set /P line=
   echo(!line:*:=!
)
echo ^<?ph^p
echo ^if(!$user->is_logged_in())^{ 
echo ^header('Location: login.php'); ^} 
echo ^?^>
:copyRestOfLines
   set /P line= 
   if "!line!" == ":EOF" exit /b
   echo(!line:*:=!
goto copyRestOfLines
```

This is the batch code its supposed to make

```
<?php
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
 header('Location: login.php'); } 
 ?>
```

But instead i get

```
<?php
header('Location: login.php'); } 
?>
```

If anyone can help me with this I would be hugely grateful as this saves me editing thirteen thousand files to add them three lines of code in.

Thanks for your time and i hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

I think, you didn't get the concept of escaping characters (by `^`)

It is used to escape special characters. The only special characters that needs to be escaped in your example are `>` and `<`

```
echo ^<?php
echo if(!$user-^>is_logged_in()){ 
echo header('Location: login.php'); } 
echo ?^>
```

PS: don't forget to delete the file `is_logged_in()){`